# An entire function $f$ satisfying $|f'(z)|\leq |f(z)|$ takes the form $f(z)=\beta e^{\alpha z}$ where, $|\alpha|\leq 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, analytic-functions, entire-functions

Let $f:\Bbb{C}\rightarrow\Bbb{C}$ be an entire function such that $|f'(z)|\leq|f(z)|$ for all $z\in\Bbb{C}$. Show that, there exists $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{C}$ with $|\alpha|\leq 1$ such that  $f(z)=\beta e^{\alpha z}$ for all $ z\in\Bbb{C}$.

I am kind of hoping that, we have to take $g(z)=\log(f(z))$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Then the given condition gives $|g'(z)|\leq1$. Then using Liouville's theorem, $g'(z)$ is constant function, equals to \alpha and so on. But there is a flaw in this approach, that is Liouville's theorem can not be used, as $g(z)$ is not defined on whole $\Bbb{C}$.

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Assume $f$ not identically zero. By [Riemann’s extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem), $f’(z)/f(z)$ extends to an entire bounded function. By [Liouville’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), this must be a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume $f$ is not identically $0$ (since $0$ does satisfy the condition, with $\beta=0$).

Suppose $f$ has a zero at $p$.  If this has order $1$, $f'$ has no zero there, and $|f'(p)|>|f(p)|$.  If it has order $m > 1$, $f'$ has order $m-1$, and $\lim_{z \to p} |f'(z)|/|f(z)| = \infty$.

Conclude $f$ has no zeros, and use Liouville on $f'/f$.

Comment: The limit is taking the $\frac{0}{0}$ form but how is that tending to $\infinity$? Please explain.

Comment: If $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $p$, $f(z) \sim c (z - p)^m$ and $f'(z) \sim m c (z-p)^{m-1}$, so $f'(z)/f(z) \sim m/(z-p)$

Comment: Oh, yes now I got it. Thank you.